# when IPFS to safari, chrome and firefox mobile and webview?

Tags: android, mobile, webview, wkwebview, ipfs

IPFS status in May 2021 : brave, opera, (chrome + firefox but with addon on desktop)

I'm wondering when ipfs will be ported to chrome and safari mobile => **especially for webview**

because those links, won't open in webview or chrome mobile or safari mobile...

`<a href="ipfs://QmT5NvUtoM5nWFfrQdVrFtvGfKFmG7AHE8P34isapyhCxX/" />test</a>`

only this will work

`<a href="https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmT5NvUtoM5nWFfrQdVrFtvGfKFmG7AHE8P34isapyhCxX/wiki/Mars.html" />test</a>`

is it because we would have to implement ipfs node natively in the app ?

Comment: This is probably better suited for the github repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it will ever come to iOS except as a native implementation because of the OS' locked-down nature, which means it’ll be a while as we wait for IPFS to become more mainstream.

Comment: doing some research, there is a nice alternative : https://filebase.com/

Answer (score 4):

IPFS availability in native webviews:

- iOS would require operating system support
- Android does allow replacing the default browser engine for webviews - so it is technically possible for native support on Android

Outside of webviews, here's a state of IPFS on mobile browsers:

- Opera Android and iOS both support ipfs:// and ipns:// addresses, which directs requests to a remote IPFS gateway.
- Brave Android and iOS are both in progress for similar support
- No progress on Chrome, Firefox

Native IPFS nodes:

- Berty has built gomobile-ipfs, a full IPFS node, tuned for mobile performance, with Kotlin and Swift bindings, which is designed for embedding into native mobile apps: https://github.com/ipfs-shipyard/gomobile-ipfs